# MongoDB print distance between two points

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

When I am firing this query on MongoDB, I am getting all the places in the proximity of 500 miles to the specified co-ordinates. But I want to know the exact distance between the specified co-ordinates and the result location.

```
db.new_stores.find({ "geometry": { $nearSphere: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -81.093699, 32.074673 ] }, $maxDistance: 500 * 3963 } } } ).pretty()
```

My Output looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565172058bc200b0db0f75b1"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -80.148826,
            25.941116
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "Name" : "Anthony's Coal Fired Pizza",
        "Address" : "17901 Biscayne Blvd, Aventura, FL"
    }
}
```

I also want to know the distance of this place from the specified co-ordinate. I created 2dsphere index on geometry.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) aggregate pipeline stage to produce a distance from the queried point:

```js
 db.new_stores.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ -81.093699, 32.074673 ]
        }, 
        "maxDistance": 500 * 1609,
        "key" : "myLocation",
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "distanceMultiplier": 0.000621371
    }}
]).pretty()
```

This allows you to specify `"distanceField"` which will produce another field in the output documents containing the distance from the queried point. You can also use `"distanceMultiplier"` to apply any conversion to the output distance as required ( i.e meters to miles, and noting that all GeoJSON distances are returned in meters )

There is also the [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command with similar options, but it of course does not return a cursor as output.

if you have more than one 2dsphere, you should specify a `"key"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working perfectly. Curious to know why did you multiply it by 1609?

Comment: @SiMemon Because there are 1609 meters in a mile, and vice/versa on the distanceMultiplier. The 3963 number you were using is the conversion of "radians" to miles, which when used with GeoJSON point coordinates would be incorrect. Radians are only used with both storage and query are using "legacy coordinate pairs".

Comment: Can we find distance from queried point to multiple geopoints in same query instead of one?

Comment: Could this determine if two circles intersect? That is, suppose I have a collection which contains a latitude and longitude, as well as a radius. Since GeoJSON does not support circles, could I write a query to determine the distance between two points, and then check if that distance is less than the sum of both radii? Would that work and would it be performant? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

MongoDB provides a **$geoNear** aggregator for calculating the distance of documents in a collection with GeoJson coordinates.

Let us understand it with a simple example.
Consider a simple collection shops

***1. Create Collection***

```
db.createCollection('shops')
```

***2. Insert documents in shops collections***

```
db.shops.insert({name:"Galaxy store",address:{type:"Point",coordinates:[28.442894,77.341299]}})

db.shops.insert({name:"A2Z store",address:{type:"Point",coordinates:[28.412894,77.311299]}})

db.shops.insert({name:"Mica store",address:{type:"Point",coordinates:[28.422894,77.342299]}})

db.shops.insert({name:"Full Stack developer",address:{type:"Point",coordinates:[28.433894,77.334299]}})
```

***3. create GeoIndex on "address" fields***

```
db.shops.createIndex({address: "2dsphere" } )
```

***4. Now use a **$geoNear** aggregator***
to find out the documents with distance.

```
db.shops.aggregate([{$geoNear:{near:{type:"Point",coordinates:[28.411134,77.331801]},distanceField: "shopDistance",$maxDistance:150000,spherical: true}}]).pretty()
```

Here **coordinates:[28.411134,77.331801]** is the center position or quired position from where documents will be fetched.

*****distanceField:"shopDistance"***** , $geoNear Aggregator return shopDistance as fields in result.

***Result:***

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef047a4715e6ae00d0893ca"), "name" : "Full Stack developer", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 28.433894, 77.334299 ] }, "shopDistance" : 621.2848190449148 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef0479e715e6ae00d0893c9"), "name" : "Mica store", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 28.422894, 77.342299 ] }, "shopDistance" : 1203.3456146763526 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef0478a715e6ae00d0893c7"), "name" : "Galaxy store", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 28.442894, 77.341299 ] }, "shopDistance" : 1310.9612119555288 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef04792715e6ae00d0893c8"), "name" : "A2Z store", "address" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ 28.412894, 77.311299 ] }, "shopDistance" : 2282.6640175038788 }
```

Here shopDistance will be in meter.

Answer (score 0):

maxDistance ->   Optional. The maximum distance from the center point that the documents can be. MongoDB limits the results to those documents that fall within the specified distance from the center point.

**Specify the distance in meters if the specified point is GeoJSON and in radians if the specified point is legacy coordinate pairs.**

In the docs it says if you use **legacy pairs , eg : near : [long , lat]** , then specify the maxDistance in **radians**.
If you user GeoJSON , eg : **near : { type : "Point" , coordinates : [long ,lat] }**,
then specify the maxDistance in **meters**.

Answer (score 0):

Use $geoNear to get the distance between a given location and users.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {"$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ longitude, latitude]
        },
        "distanceField": "distance",
        "distanceMultiplier": 1/1000,
        "query": {/* userConditions */},
    }}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).