# How can i calculate the euclidean distance between two array of 128D?

Tags: mongodb, euclidean-distance

I am developing software that stores 128D vector with SIFT descriptor of an image. Then I want to get all image similars to a given image, but the similarity between image are the euclidean distance. 
How can i calculate the euclidean distance between this vectors?

Comment: The [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) page on Wikipedia may be worth reviewing.  Not sure what this has to do with [tag:mongodb]

Comment: You cannot (reasonably) do this calculation inside of MongoDB. You'll have to do that in application code.

Answer (score -2):

MongoDB supports 2d indexes and geospatial queries. Please first check [2d Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/) to know how to properly structure the index.

After that, you can [calculate the Euclidian distance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) on a 2d plane with queries.

Also check this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864461/mongodb-print-distance-between-two-points). (But remember not to set `spherical` to `true`, since your space is 2D).

Comment: It just required to store embedding into the column and need to find square root using aggregation