# How to find distance between two fields in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

My collection *Col1* has two fields *loc1* and *loc2*. I need to check if *loc1* is father than *loc2* by X km. Getting calculated distance would be fine too. I would greatly prefer not to create new collections.

I am dealing with 3.6.7 mongoDB using it's shell for testing.
There are 2dsphere indexes on both *loc1* and *loc2*.
I failed both with `geoNear` aggregation and with `nearSphere` query operator. Both do not like having a variable as there main search parameter.

I expect to either get some "distance" or just to check if *loc1* is father than *loc2* by X kilometers (like `nearShere` does with `maxDistance`)

This is once-in-a-while scheduled script, so I do not care about how fast or efficient it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB print distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864461/mongodb-print-distance-between-two-points)

Comment: Hi David. That question is about the distance from specified point (coordinate pair). And setting up $loc1 as that value in aggregation didn't work for me.