# Get distance between two geo-locations from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to get the distance between two points on a 2dsphere from MongoDB using Go.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33864605/4261333) and tried this

```
conditions["geolocation"] = bson.M{
        "$geoNear": bson.M{
            "near": bson.M{
                "type":        "Point",
                "coordinates": []float64{latitude, longitude},
            },
            "maxDistance":   rangeInMeters,
            "spherical":     true,
            "distanceField": "distance",
        },
    }

filterCursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, conditions)
```

But I get this error : **"Invalid arguement in geo near query:near"**

Answer (score 0):

The [Mentioned Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864461/mongodb-print-distance-between-two-points/33864605#33864605)
 uses MongoDB [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) function.

You can do that with golang like follows :

```
    stages := mongo.Pipeline{}
    getNearbyStage := bson.D{{"$geoNear", bson.M{
        "near": bson.M{
            "type":        "Point",
            "coordinates": []float64{longitude, latitude},
        },
        "maxDistance":   rangeInMeters,
        "spherical":     true,
        "distanceField": "distance",
    }}}
    stages = append(stages, getNearbyStage)

    filterCursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, stages)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
```

If you want to add another query to the pipleline you can simply make another stage and append it to the stages slice

also check this quick guide on how to use Aggregation Pipelines in golang & mongo [Golang & MongoDB - Data Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang--mongodb--data-aggregation-pipeline)